# PowerAutomate Flow query lookup threshold issue SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I am trying to use get item action in my flow to fetch data from a SharePoint list having 3000+ items.

I am getting lookup column Threshold error while fetching the records even if only 2 lookup/choice/person columns are there. For each lookup field I have to create a new view which is not a suitable approach.

I am not sure why I am getting this error even with 2 columns whereas lookup field limit is 8.

Please assist.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT                                      Please assist

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start with Some **Back ground information**

1. With Microsoft power automate when try to retrieve items from a
   SharePoint list which as more than 12 looks column you will receive
   'lookup column threshold' error
2. In Microsoft Sharepoint following column types are defined as lookup columns:

   ```
    a. Standard lookup columns

    b. Managed metadata columns 

    c. People and groups Columns

    d. Workflow Status columns 

    e. System generated fields 

    f. Created by and Modified by 

    g. Name (linked to Document) 

    i. Link (Edit to edit item) 

    j. Name (linked to Document with edit menu) 

    k. Type (icon linked to document)
   ```

**Solution**

1. Create/Modify SharePoint List view with no more than 12 lookup columns.
2. In Microsoft power automate use the view created/Modified in the above step has a maximum of 11 lookup columns.
3. Use the List view at the below point of get items action . Screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am trying to do the same by creting a view with less number of lookup fields. But in this list, even with 2 lookup fields in view, i am getting threshold issue although the limit is 12. i cant even add two lookup columns in view to make it work. Please assist